# serialization.null.format for Hive ORC table

Tags: hive, orc

I have a Hive table where the data is stored as ORC.
Now, when I run a select * query on this table I see that the empty string columns are shown as NULL in the query result.
I would like the empty string columns to be shown as empty strings in the hive query result as well.

I tried both of these, but it still shows the NULLs:

```
ALTER TABLE temp_table set SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = "");
ALTER TABLE temp_table set TBLPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = "");
```

Also tried giving single quotes:

```
ALTER TABLE temp_table set SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = '');
ALTER TABLE temp_table set TBLPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = '');
```

Storage properties of the hive table:

```
# Storage Information        
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde    
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat  
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat     
Compressed:             No                       
Num Buckets:            -1                       
Bucket Columns:         []                       
Sort Columns:           []                       
Storage Desc Params:         
        serialization.format    1                   
        serialization.null.format
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: AFAIK these "serialization" props are applicable to Text or SequenceFile formats; and they define the way NULLs are **stored**, not how they are displayed. The newer, much more complex row formats (AVRO) or columnar formats (ORC, Parquet) have their own way of storing NULLs.

Comment: Besides, NULL is a concept that has been around in SQL, and even before that, for decades. You won't change the concept to fit your whims.

Comment: What you could have done was to **handle NULLs when you created the ORC files**, e.g. with `INSERT ... SELECT case when ZZ is Null then '' else ZZ end ...`

Comment: And what you can do now is **handle NULLs at read time**, the same way. Creating a VIEW might be easier (conversions defined once and for all).

Comment: Hi @James Isaac, 

did you get more information on this, that you can share ? Thanks

Comment: @Kanav Sharma, I believe we can only handle NULLs on read, as Samson Scharfrichter suggested. It's been nearly a year; I haven't looked into the problem after that.

Comment: @James Isaac thanks.